# have I invented a new sorting algorithm? or is this the same as quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, in-place

I made an algorithm for sorting but I then I thought perhaps I had just reinvented quicksort.

However I heard quicksort is O(N^2) worst case; I think my algorithm should be only O(NLogN) worst case.

Is this the same as quicksort?

The algorithm works by swapping values so that all values smaller than the median are moved to the left of the array. It then works recursively on each side.

The algorithm starts with i=0, j = n-1

i and j move towards each other with list[i] and list[j] being swapped if necessary.

Here is some code for the first iteration before the recursion:

```
_list = [1,-4,2,-5,3,-6]

def in_place(_list,i,j,median):
    while i<j:
        a,b = _list[i],_list[j]
        if (a<median and b>=median):
            i+=1
            j-=1
        elif (a>=median and b<median):
            _list[i],_list[j]=b,a
            i+=1
            j-=1
        elif a<median:
            i+=1
        else:
            j-=1
    print "changed to ", _list



def get_median(_list):
    #approximate median in O(N) with O(1) space
    return -4

median = get_median(_list)
in_place(_list,0,len(_list)-1,median)

"""
changed1 to  [-6, -5, 2, -4, 3, 1]
"""
```

Comment: IIUC get_median is called approximately log(N) times. In that case your algoritm is similar to quicksort ("pivot") (But I don't understand Python)

Comment: I just saw TimSort. It uses "runs". perhaps this could be optimized to use runs also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Selection-based_pivoting

> Conversely, once we know a worst-case O(n) selection algorithm is
> available, we can use it to find the ideal pivot (the median) at every
> step of quicksort, producing a variant with worst-case O(n log n)
> running time. In practical implementations, however, this variant is
> considerably slower on average.
>
> Another variant is to choose the Median of Medians as the pivot
> element instead of the median itself for partitioning the elements.
> While maintaining the asymptotically optimal run time complexity of
> O(n log n) (by preventing worst case partitions), it is also
> considerably faster than the variant that chooses the median as pivot.

Comment: While I agree that this is not a new algorithm, or even a new method of pivot choice, I would argue median of three is not the same as median of n. Particularly, I think median of n pivot choice combined with 3 way partitioning (which he does not mention/show), would actually guarantee O(n*log n).

Comment: Karoly, so what you're saying is that this varient of quicksort is O(NLogN) and not O(N^2) as I had thought, so the fact that my algorithm might not be O(N^2) doesn't mean it's not quicksort..

Comment: yes. yes and no. it's a variant of it. not the classic quicksort.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, I assume there is other code not shown, as I'm pretty sure that the code you've shown on its own would not work.

I'm sorry to steal your fire, but I'm afraid what code you do show seems to be Quicksort, and not only that, but the code seems to possibly suffer from some bugs.

Consider the case of sorting a list of identical elements. Your `_in_place` method, which seems to be what is traditionally called partition in Quicksort, would not move any elements correctly, but at the end the `j` and `i` seem to reflect the list having only one partition containing the whole list, in which case you would recurse again on the whole list forever. My guess is, as as mentioned, you don't return anything from it, or seem to actually fully sort anywhere, so I am left guessing how this would be used.

I'm afraid using the real median for Quicksort is not only a possibly fairly slow strategy in the average case, it also doesn't avoid the O(n^2) worst case, again a list of identical elements would provide such a worst case. However, I think a three way partition Quicksort with such a median selection algorithm would guarantee O(n*log n) time. Nonetheless, this is a known option for pivot choice and not a new algorithm.

In short, this appears to be an incomplete and possibly buggy Quicksort, and without three way partitioning, using the median would not guarantee you O(n*log n). However, I do feel that it is a good thing and worth congratulations that you did think of the idea of using the median yourself - even if it has been thought of by others before.

Comment: I think the all elements are equal problem can be solved with `if (a<=median and b>=median) i+=1 j-=1`

Comment: I may be wrong, but I can't see that anywhere in his code - there's a<= and b>, and a< and b>=. I think that case would just be j-=1.

Comment: thanks for the response. I just thought this might be different from quicksort because it only swaps values, quicksort moves the pivot from the right towards the middle. I'm not too worried about bugs as long as they can be fixed. I think if all elements are equal then j goes to 0 and you could have logic to choose not to recurse in this case (by comparing j to the original i). The only reason I used the median was to try make the first two partitions larger, although later there could be a good way of approximating the medium of each partition.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: My apologies, I hadn't noticed you meant adding that would fix it - I agree.

robertking: I see what you mean, but as the pivot is generally moved only twice in a normal quicksort (once to put it at the end/start out of the way, and then once to put it in the middle at the end of partitioning), this is only cutting out O(n) work when the partitioning is not degenerate, not enough to change the complexity.

My suggestion would be three way partitioning if you're using the true median - no need to move the pivot around then, and it should be O(n*log n) worst case.